# Use of umbilicals with Vacuum Circuit Breakers

Tags: circuit-protection

I am a trainee systems engineer and have been tasked with drawing up symbols for mimics for a SCADA system. One of the symbols I have been asked to draw up is for a vacuum circuit breaker. When it is isolated an umbilical cable is supposed to be attached. I tried reading up on what the umbilical is supposed to do but couldn't find anything useful. Maybe I am just searching with the wrong keywords. Can anyone on here explain what umbilicals are supposed to do in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some misunderstanding but finally the question is clear I hope.
Before the vacuum breaker is isolated (disconnected from the rails) it must be deactivated. (Remote or locally).

When thereafter the breaker is isolated (disconnected from the rails) all power connections are disconnected. The remote station is still able to communicate with the breaker with SCADA.

This to prevent the situation that the breaker is pushed back in an active state.(Could be very dangerous) both SCADA and mechanical measures are in place to make this impossible.

Therefore the SCADA system must be able to communicate with the breaker as long as it is on the rails in the cubicle. This is realised with the umbilical (a flexible data cable) connected to the breaker.

When the breaker is racked out for further inspection or replacement (Removed from the cubicle) the umbilical needs to be disconnected and communication with SCADA is lost.

After the same or an replacement breaker is put back on the rails for service the umbilical needs to be connected before any further action. This way the remote station is informed about the status and the actions with the breaker.

When information from SCADA and the additional mechanical protections are released the breaker can be pushed back into the cubicle (breaker is still open). Thereafter the breaker can be activated locally or remote.

The expression umbilical comes from the possibility that the cable set can be plugged in and out.

Comment: So when breakers are isolated (racked out), would the umbilicals be used to bypass the breaker OR to maintain a data connection with the breaker to the SCADA system so the engineers can tell if a breaker is closed or open before racking in again to avoid arcs?

Comment: I think the question is about why the "Umbilical cable" is supposed to be connected when the vacuum circuit breaker is isolated.

Comment: The sole purpose of the umbilical in a shielded situation is to maintain the shield and depending on the situation mechanical protection. Information about the status of the breaker is to be incorporated in the data handling.

Comment: By isolated do you mean an open breaker?

Comment: @diverger: Maybe my English forms a problem. What does OP mean by isolated. An open or disconnected breaker. Or a breaker that is completely sealed.

Comment: @Decapod: From the comment above, the OP means "racked out", maybe the link below can give some information: http://dealertraining.cat.com/jobaids/elpdf/eb05ja.pdf

Comment: @diverger: I have rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in Aerospace and designed instruments for rockets, the launch pad interface was through 50 wire connectors of varying wire gauges for choosing signals power or coax.

I think the distinction between a "cable" which has 2 connectors and a "harness" which has more than two connectors and an "umbilical" cable is that one end can be disconnected quickly or by a pulling force.

I also designed a complex SCADA system back there in the late 70's, with lots of cables, but the only "umbilical" cables were the ones provided to interface our equipment on site to our rockets which separate from the cables on launch.

Here are an ABB drawing of their vacuum switch boxes for your interest.
[image]

You might just show a box with an umbilical cable and other cables with a wiring list for details.